# Acronym or initialism presentation

Tags: word-usage

When creating an acronyms/initialisms in a document which will be referenced throughout the document, what is the proper way to display it for the first time? ("Word") or just (Word)?

Comment: Can you add an example, please?

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to introduce your acronym is to write out the entire phrase in the body of the text, then introduce the acronym in parentheses after it.

> ...we have examined the effect of new acronym generation (NAG) on comprehensibility of...

Answer (score 1):

Define the three-letter acronym (TLA) on first use, then use the abbreviated form in subsequent mentions.